# Is a million users hitting one file on the server the same as a million users hitting a million different files?

Tags: resource-management

Is a million users hitting one file on the server the same as a million users hitting a million different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the web server.

However, static files are likely to be cached in memory, so I would assume that 1 million users accessing the same file will be faster.

Comment: What if its a dynamic file thats doing processing on the request coming in? the file basically acts as a gateway file.

Comment: Then the performance would _probably_ equivalent.  However, you should measure.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking because to the server a million files or one million instances of that same file is the same thing. Ill try to measure the usage and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on server configuration and software. You'll need to measure.